# how can i insert 2 or many different list in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

hello can some help me to add 2 list to a database(mysql) in python, here is the code but i can figure out where is the problem (i am new to mysql).

```
def scan(self):
        """Scan the pc for instaled app in `desktop`"""
        file_location = []
        file_name = []
        ending = ('.url','.lnk','.rtf')
        desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']),'OneDrive', 'Desktop')
        exclude = set(['one drive'])
        for r, dirs, f in os.walk(desktop, topdown=True):
            dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
            for file in f:
                if file.endswith(ending):
                    file_location.append(r + "\\" + file)
            for f_name in os.listdir(desktop):
                if f_name.endswith(tuple(ending)):
                    file_name.append(f_name)
        query2 = ("INSERT INTO application (app_name) VALUES (%s)")
        query3 = ("INSERT INTO application (app_location) VALUES (%s)")
        my_cursor.executemany(query2, [(n, ) for n in file_name])
        my_cursor.executemany(query3, [(l, ) for l in file_location])
        mydb.commit()
```

and this is the error that i have:

> TypeError: executemany() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

the result that i need is to place `file_name` and `file_location` in the same row but different colon respectively
ex:

file_name | file_location

fornite   | fortnite.exe

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21734918/5320906) but use `%s` instead of `?`.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute the query with only this:

```
i = 0 
while i < len(file_location):
  my_cursor.execute("INSERT INTO application app_name , app_location VALUES" + str(file_name[i]) + "," + str(file_location[i]))
  i = i + 1
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: thx for the help